# Unable to deserialize a JSON string generated by a JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, serialization

I using a JQuery plugin that enable my users to design forms. The design is saved in form of a JSON string in database. This JSON string is in following format:

```
{
    "fields": [{
        "label": "Untitled",
        "field_type": "text",
        "required": true,
        "field_options": {
            "save_to": "",
            "size": "small",
            "description": ""
        },
        "cid": "c5"
    }]
}
```

Following is C# class structure and code that is used to deserialize this JSON string:

```
public class Options {
    public string label {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool Checked {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class FieldOption {
    public string save_to {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string description {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public object options {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool include_other_option {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string size {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class DesignField {
    public string label {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string field_type {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool required {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string cid {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List < FieldOption > field_options {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class Design {
    public List < DesignField > fields {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public partial class FormDesign: System.Web.UI.UserControl {
    List < DesignField > FormFields;
    public string FormDesignData {
        get;
        set;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Design res = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize < Design > (FormDesignData);

         }
}
```

JSON Helper class is given here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET

The problem is that it is deserializing when inner JSON objects are enclosed with `[]` for example:

```
"field_options":[{
            "save_to": "",
            "size": "small",
            "description": ""
        }]
```

But the plugin is not exporting the JSON in that format but in the format I mentioned before.

Please tell me how can I convert it to a valid deserializable format?

Comment: You have field_options as a list. It's not. It's a single object. The [] would mean it's an array. Since it doesn't have that, it's a single object.

Comment: @dman2306 thanks a lot. It worked. Add it as answer I will mark it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The model according to your json should be:

```
public class FieldOptions
{
    public string save_to { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string field_type { get; set; }
    public bool required { get; set; }
    public FieldOptions field_options { get; set; }
    public string cid { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
}
```

I used this online tool http://json2csharp.com/ to generate it.

*RootObject* is the type you will use to deserialize

Using, for ex, [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), your code would be

```
var myobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```